# how to send a GET request with Json body in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, get, restful-url

I need to send a GET HTTP request with a JSON body. I know that this is not allowed by the RestFul specs. However, there is no chance to change the server. Is there a way to overcome this restriction in Flutter?

This is the code I am trying to use but I couldn't find a way to insert the body.

```
String urlGetkey = "https://pa.me/transactions/card_hash_key";
   Map userHeader = {
     "Content-type": "application/json",
     "Accept": "application/json",
     "User-Agent": "curl/7.64.",
   };

   var _body = jsonEncode({"api_key": zulu});
   
   var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse(urlGetkey));
   request.body = _body;

   final streamedResponse = await request.send();
   var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
'''

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: It would be non-standard for a GET request to have a body. Do you have any documentation for this API?

Comment: Thanks Richard ! Yes, The API company knows about that but they cannot change the request from GET to POST.

Comment: According to https://docs.pagar.me/reference/autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-2 your key should be going in a header not the body. And this usage https://pagarme.github.io/pagarme-js/resources_transactions.js.html definitely shows an empty body. Where are you seeing that there should be a JSON body for this request?

Comment: I am talking with the API provider engineers. They have hundreds of customer using the API. They will not change it. Thank

Comment: curl   -X GET https://api.pagar.me/1/transactions/card_hash_key -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{ 
    "api_key": "ak_test_46po64VBDm3aqJmR8oXvFLqQbi0VxtP"
}'
Please, test thi curl rquest

Comment: That gives this, but not sure what the invalid param is: {"errors":[{"type":"invalid_parameter","parameter_name":"","message":"Chave inválida.

Comment: curl   -X GET https://api.pagar.me/1/transactions/card_hash_key -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{
    "api_key": "ak_test_46po64VBDm3aqJmR8oXvFLqQi0VxtP"
}'

Comment: this is the correct key. How should I program the request in flutter to do exactly what the CURL command does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, but you need to use a subclass of `BaseRequest` so that you can add the body, which you can do by grabbing its sink and adding the body to that before then sending the request.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  final payload = '{"api_key":"ak_test_46po64VBDm3aqJmR8oXvFLqQi0VxtP"}';

  final request = http.StreamedRequest(
    'GET',
    Uri.https(
      'api.pagar.me',
      '/1/transactions/card_hash_key',
    ),
  );

  request.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';
  request.sink
    ..add(utf8.encode(payload))
    ..close();
  final streamedResponse = await request.send();

  final response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);

  print(response.statusCode);
  print(response.body);
}
```

Comment: I edited the code to make it simpler. See the earlier edit for re-use of the client if making multiple requests to the same server.